# Append select box value to prev p tag for multiple boxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like this which will append the select boxes multiple times. I have to get the selected value to be appended to the respective p class="managerName" tag. The combo of p &select box will be mutiple times as per user input. Need to implement this in jquery. Any solutions?? Facing issues

```
<p class="managerName"><span class='iconManager'></span></p>
<select onchange="SalesManager(this)" class="SalesManager">
   <option value="map roles">Map Roles</option>
   <option value="National_Manager">National Manager</option>
   <option value="Regional_Manager">Regional Manager</option>
   <option value="Area_Manager">Area Manager</option>
   <option value="Divisional_Manager">Divisional Manager</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with a minor change in the html - because looks like you want to keep the icon even after the manager value is displayed

```
<p class="managerName"><span class='iconManager'></span><span class='manager'></span>
</p>
<select class="SalesManager">
    <option value="map roles">Map Roles</option>
    <option value="National_Manager">National Manager</option>
    <option value="Regional_Manager">Regional Manager</option>
    <option value="Area_Manager">Area Manager</option>
    <option value="Divisional_Manager">Divisional Manager</option>
</select>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.SalesManager').change(function () {
        $(this).prev('.managerName').find('span.manager').html(this.value)
    });
})
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y7ZkF/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#SalesManager').on('change',function () {
    $('p span[class=iconManager]').text(this.value);
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PHfpc/)